# Limit file size to 2 MB for fileUpload Lightning compoennt

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, files, fileupload

I have a requirement where i need to restrict the user to not upload the file size more than 2 MB. We are using **lightning:fileUpload** , for which i don't see any size parameter.

We are uploading file from 3 places for same object. We need restriction only in one place.

All please suggest on how we can limit the size on file upload.    .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to write a trigger on ContentVersion which would check size of file, if more just add error

Comment: We are uploading file from 3 places for same object. We need only in one place

Comment: SO you want that 2mb limitation everywhere?

Comment: no only in one place

Comment: @Adrian Larson Please help on this

Comment: @sfdcfox Please help on this

Comment: You can't do this in lightning:fileUpload. There's no way to set a limit like this. We had to end up writing a custom component to gain better control over the upload process.

Comment: You can add a custom field to ContentVersion and set it in the fileUpload and use that on your trigger to differentiate between the file upload locations and then error on the size when that field has your value.